# Table column width "fill to margin"

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I kind of would expect tables to be able to "fill to margin", instead of choosing a number and iteratively rebuilding the document until it is the right size.

For example, I want this 2-column table to have the first column as wide as it needs to be, and the 2nd column to "fill to margin":

```
\begin{tabular}{ l p{5cm} }
```

Of course, that's not gonna do it (2nd column will be `5cm`), is there anyway to "fill to margin"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `tabularx` package provides the `tabularx` environment, which was designed for just this purpose.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
    foo & bar
\end{tabularx}
\caption{My table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that `tabularx`'s first argument is the width of the table. In the above, I have chosen `\textwidth`; when combined with the `X` columntype (defined in the `tabularx` package), it produces the 'fill-to-margin' effect that you want.

Comment: Note that if you do not put the `tabularx` in a `table` environment and just use it in text, prepend it with `\notindent` to avoid it sticking out the right margin by `\parindent`.

Comment: I think that I may be having the problem you describe in your comment. The right column of my table is extending too far to the right, beyond the text column (I'm using a two-column article). Where do I put \notindent? Or presumably, \noindent...

Comment: @NelsBeckman if you're not using the `table` environment, then you could use `\noindent\begin{tabular}`...

Comment: This inserts itself at the top of my document.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this *without* any additional packages, by simply using the `tabular*` environment, and add `\extracolsep{\fill}` to fill the column.  Here is an example of before and after (I also removed the left column spacing in column 1, and the right column spacing after column 2) where the `geometry` package was used to include the frame:

[image]

### Custom Column Type:

If you use this type of column often, you can use [the `array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) and define a custom column type as I have done for the last table.  So, with this just using `L` for your column will achieve what you want.  This produces results identical to the second example in the above picture.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}% Only needed if you want to be able to use the `L` column type
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}% Needs `array` package

\newcommand*{\Text}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta tincidunt velit, at lacinia ipsum dictum eget.}

\begin{document}\vspace*{0.1cm}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l p{5cm} }\hline
abc & \Text\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}} p{5cm}@{}}\hline
abc & \Text\\\hline
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{L p{5cm}@{}}\hline% Using the L column type
abc & \Text\\\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{} }
    as long as its contents & \lipsum[1]
\end{tabularx}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The left and right columns are algned with the text