# Fit large table horizontally into a page

Tags: tables

I have a table with 23 columns. How can I fit it to the page?

Code:

```
\usepackage[verbose]{placeins}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
    \begin{table}[htbf]
    \caption{Gross errors found using plausible value check}
    \label{tab:gr}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  l  c  c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c  }
           \toprule
             \textbf{Node Name} &\textbf{Node 2} &\textbf{Node 3} &\textbf{Node 4} &\textbf{Node 5} &\textbf{Node 6} &\textbf{Node 7} &\textbf{Node 8} &\textbf{Node 9} &\textbf{Node 10} &\textbf{Node 11} &\textbf{Node 12} &\textbf{Node 13} &\textbf{Node 14} &\textbf{Node 15} &\textbf{Node 17} &\textbf{Node 18} &\textbf{Node 19} &\textbf{Node 20} &\textbf{Node 25} &\textbf{Node 28} &\textbf{Node 29} &\textbf{Node 31} &\textbf{Node 32} \\
           \midrule
             \textbf{Total Number Observations} 33 & 34 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33  \\
             \textbf{Number of Faults} & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33  \\

           \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
\blindtext
```

Result:
[image: Result of the code]  Result of the code

Comment: Even at 5pt size, typesetting "Node 10" requires more than 27pt; so this table, at `\tiny` size will occupy much more than 600pt, which is way wider than the text width. Impossible to set at 75% of the text width.

Comment: With that many columns you may need to consider swaping the rows and columns or rotating it for the table to be readable.  You can force the table to be resized to fit the `textwidth` but that will resize the font as well and therefore may make the text too small to read.

Comment: Related: [Fit a table into one page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29195/5764); [Scaling a table to fit an entire page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35987/5764); [How to shrink a table automatically so that it fits onto a page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63651/5764); [How to fit a wide table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71419/5764); and perhaps many more...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try and spare on intercolumn spaces, by locally reducing the value of `\tabcolsep`; also the headers should be as short as possible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show the margins
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

Here is a table

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{6pt}} *{22}{c}}
\toprule
\bfseries Type & \multicolumn{22}{c}{\bfseries Node name} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-23}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 \\
\midrule
\bfseries A
& 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33
& 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 \\
\bfseries B
& 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33
& 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{23}{l}{A: Total number of observations}\\
\multicolumn{23}{l}{B: Number of faults}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Observations}\label{tab:observ}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to refine this code? \begin{table}[htp]
\footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{6pt}} *{22}{c}}
\toprule
\bfseries Type & \multicolumn{22}{c}{\bfseries Node name} \\cmidrule(l){3-23}
& 25 & 28 & 29 & 31 & 32 \\midrule
\bfseries TNO
& 20276 & 20302 & 20267 & 20263 & 20257  \\bfseries NOF
& 1376 & 1321 & 83 & 1329 & 1502  \\bfseries NOFI
& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{23}{l}{A: Total number of observations}\\multicolumn{23}{l}{B: Number of faults}
\multicolumn{23}{l}{C:in 2007-09-29}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Comment: @aliamidi It's better if you add the data to your question so it's more easily parseable.

Comment: What do you mean by data?

Comment: @aliamidi The code you added in the comment. If it's in the question it can be looked at more easily.

Comment: Actually, I have used your proposed code but the problem occurred in performing.

Comment: @aliamidi I don't understand. But if the numbers in the table have four digits, I think it's quite hopeless to try and squeeze the table in the text width. Can you add some of the *actual* numbers in your example?

Comment: There are actual numbers. And I will present the table with these numbers, but the line which separate the rows is short and doesn't fit with data length.

Answer (score 16):

Please try to ensure your question has a complete document that shows all packages used (I had to guess `booktabs`) and avoids unrelated errors

! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

However

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{graphicx,rotating,booktabs}

\usepackage[verbose]{placeins}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

    \begin{sidewaystable}[htbf]
    \caption{Gross errors found using plausible value check}
    \label{tab:gr}
  \bigskip
    \centering\small\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
        \hspace*{-1cm}\begin{tabular}{l  c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c  }
           \toprule
             \textbf{Name} &\textbf{2} &\textbf{3} &\textbf{4} &\textbf{5} &\textbf{6} &\textbf{7} &\textbf{8} &\textbf{9} &\textbf{10} &\textbf{11} &\textbf{12} &\textbf{13} &\textbf{14} &\textbf{15} &\textbf{17} &\textbf{18} &\textbf{19} &\textbf{20} &\textbf{25} &\textbf{28} &\textbf{29} &\textbf{31} &\textbf{32} \\
           \midrule
             \textbf{Total Number Observations} 33 & 34 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33  \\
             \textbf{Number of Faults} & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33 & 33  \\

           \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}\hspace*{-1cm}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: could you please let me know how I can manage if the table is occupying two pages? The table should have the ability to continue to the next page when it is required.

Comment: @sky-light longtable and lscape packages are designed for that task (but it is better to ask a new question than leave a comment on a 4 year old one)

Comment: Ok, I will post a question referring to this question as well. Thanks.