# How to modify table recipe to get a right-justified column?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to modify the recipe given in [an earlier reply](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35672/7792) so that the right-most column (of two) is right-justified.

Here's a toy example of what I'm working with:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\begin{document}\vspace*{-1.5in}
\noindent

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}} p{5cm}@{}}
foo &         frobozz \\
bar &            quux \\
baz & yabba-dabba-doo \\
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Note that, contrary to the cited answer, this code uses `\documentclass{letter}`, not `\documentclass{article}`.  (The document is meant to be a résumé.  The table here is meant to hold address, telephone, email, etc. info.  I need to squeeze the whole thing into two pages, and I'm hoping that putting this information in two columns will give me a precious extra couple of lines.)

Also, the `\vspace*{-1.5in}` at the top is my ignorant hack to reduce the amount of space at the top of the page.

---

The recipe above works fine for me, except that the rightmost column is left-justified.  What must I do to get it to right-justify the text in the right-most column (only)?

---

I don't fully understand how this recipe works, but usually this is not a problem, because I can search for salient keywords in what I don't understand, and figure it out.  In this case, however, I don't know what to search for, largely because much of what I don't understand consists of unsearchable symbols (e.g. `@{}`).

Comment: You should really read an introduction to LaTeX.

Comment: @TeXnician: I read this book cover-to-cover https://books.google.com/books?id=MxVUAAAAMAAJ decades ago, but I no longer use LaTeX often enough to remember it.  Even when I was using LaTeX a lot (in grad school I wrote all my papers, and my dissertation with it), it still made zero sense, a hodge-podge of syntax without rhyme or reason, so I don't find it too surprising that I can't remember it...  But yeah, I should relearn it, since there's nothing better in the horizon.

Comment: Maybe you like ConTeXt more (clearer syntax…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your example:

```
\begin{document}\vspace*{-1.5in}
```

You're right, this is not a good solution. Just use `geometry` if you want to change margins (but really, if you use the `letter` class spacing should be treated carefully; which does not say that using letter for a resume is the best idea).

```
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}} p{5cm}@{}}
```

So you are defining two columns: one left-aligned `l` column and one fixed-width (justified) `p` column. The `@{}` part just removes the small horizontal extra space inserted before and after a line. The `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` just flushes the second column to the right.

For making the second column right-aligned you have three basic options:

- use a `r`-column (if you do not need line breaks)
- use the `array` package and specify `>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{5cm}`
- use the `array` package (up-to-date version) and a simple `wr{5cm}`